# Can I use my Samsung Note 8 pen and device as a stylus for my laptop?

Tags: android, samsung, input-devices, stylus

How can I use my Android Samsung note 8 as a writingpad for my Laptop? I run Ubuntu 20.4 (I believe it's the latest version)

I would like to use my phone to draw in Gimp or Inkscape. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The KDE connect app seems to do what I requested.

KDE connect is an app that connects your phone and laptop over Wifi.  (I haven't tried other methods)
With this app, you can share input, files and possibly more.